# Run .jar from batch-file

Tags: java, file, batch-file

I have created an executable `.jar` file. How can I execute the `.jar` using a batch-file without mentioning a class path?

Comment: Dude, formatting, a question is not a code segment.

Answer (score 61):

On Windows you can use the following command.

```
start javaw -jar JarFile.jar
```

By doing so, the Command Prompt Window doesn't stay open.

Comment: Windows cannot find 'javaw'. I fixed this by just having `start JarFile.jar` (with the .jar file in the same folder as the batch file).

Comment: OMG! How do you stop it now?

Comment: when I use start I am getting "windows cannot find '-jar'. Make sure you type the name correctly..."

Comment: Combining answers: `start javaw -jar %~dp0JarFile.jar %*`

Comment: How do we stop it now?

Answer (score 26):

There is a solution to this that does not require to specify the path of the jar file inside the .bat. This means the jar can be moved around in the filesystem with no changes, as long as the .bat file is always located in the same directory as the jar. The .bat code is:

```
java -jar %~dp0myjarfile.jar %*
```

Basically `%0` would expand to the .bat full path, and `%~dp0` expands to the .bat full path except the filename. So `%~dp0myjarfile.jar` is the full path of the myjarfile.jar colocated with the .bat file. `%*` will take all the arguments given to the .bat and pass it to the Java program. (see: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true )

Answer (score 20):

You can create a batch file with `.bat` extension with the following contents

Use `java` for `.jar` that does not have UI and is a command line application

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -jar <your_jar_file_name>.jar
```

Use `javaw` for `.jar` that has a UI

```
@ECHO OFF
start javaw -jar <your_jar_file_name>.jar
```

Please make sure your `JAVA_HOME` is set in the environment variables.

Comment: Precise and accurate info.Much obliged!

Answer (score 16):

If you want a batch file to run a jar file, make a blank file called runjava.bat with the contents:

```
java -jar "C:\myjarfile.jar"
```

Answer (score 10):

```
cd "Your File Location without inverted commas"
```

**example :** cd C:\Users*****\Desktop\directory\target

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

**example bat file looks like this:**

```
@echo OFF
cd C:\Users\****\Desktop\directory\target
java -jar myjar.jar
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Why without inverted commas (quotation mark)? If the path has a space in the name, you need the inverted commas.

Answer (score 7):

To run a `.jar` file from the command line, just use:

```
java -jar YourJar.jar
```

To do this as a batch file, simply copy the command to a text file and save it as a `.bat`:

```
@echo off
java -jar YourJar.jar
```

The `@echo off` just ensures that the second command is not printed.

Comment: @Carlos: I assumed that as the OP asked for a batch file, that they were using Windows.

Comment: I am using windows 7.I have the jar file in the D:\my.jar
I write the following code in my batch file
@echo off
java -jar my.jar
 and also i tried
@echo off
java -jar D:\my.jar
what can i do?

Answer (score 4):

If double-clicking the .jar file in Windows Explorer works, then you should be able to use this:

```
start myapp.jar
```

in your batch file.

The Windows `start` command does exactly the same thing behind the scenes as double-clicking a file.

Comment: It gives the error windows cannot find myapp.jar(my jar file).

Comment: @Arivu2020: Are you in the right directory?  Perhaps your batch file need to do `cd c:\path\to\my\stuff` before trying to run the jar file?

Answer (score 2):

```
java -jar "C:\\myjarfile.jar"
```

You might need to add `"\\"` to the command. Try this!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following command in the .bat file newly created:

```
@echo off
call C:\SWDTOOLS\**PATH\TO\JAVA**\java_1.7_64\jre\bin\java -jar workspace.jar
```

Please give the path of the java if there are multiple versions of java installed in the system and make sure you specified the main method and manifest file is created while creating the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is that the OP is trying to avoid specifying a class-path in his command line. You can do this by putting the class-path in the Manifest file.

In the manifest:

```
Class-Path: Library.jar
```

This document gives more details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

To create a jar using the a manifest file named MANIFEST, you can use the following command:

```
jar -cmf MANIFEST MyJar.jar <class files>
```

If you specify relative class-paths (ie, other jars in the same directory), then you can move the jar's around and the batch file mentioned in mdm's answer will still work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you specify the classpath in the MANIFEST.MF file. If you are using Maven to do the packaging, you can configure the following plugins:
1. maven-depedency-plugin:
2. maven-jar-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.plugin.maven-dependency-plugin}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.plugin.maven-jar-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resulting manifest file will be packaged in the executable jar under META-INF and will look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: myexecjar
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Built-By: razvanone
Class-Path: lib/first.jar lib/second.jar
Build-Jdk: your-buildjdk-version
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
Main-Class: ro.razvanone.MyMainClass
```

The Windows script would look like this:

```
@echo on
echo "Starting up the myexecjar application..."
java -jar myexecjar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This should be complete config for building an executable jar using Maven :)

Answer (score 0):

Just the same way as you would do in command console. Copy exactly those commands in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 
1- Create/export a runnable jar file out of your project.

2- Create a .bat file with the below content

```
@Echo off

set classpath="c:\jars\lib\*****.jar;c:\jars\lib\*****.jar;c:\extJars\****.jar"

java -cp %classpath%;c:\apps\applName\yourJar.jar com.****.****.MainMethod args1 args2 ...

@pause
```

3- set classpath is required if any external jars you are using.

4- Put the .bat file and jar file in the same folder.

5- As per the java -cp command give your exact jar file location and the fully qualified name of the main method and followed by argument list as per requirement.

Answer (score -1):

inside .bat file format

## SET CLASSPATH=%Path%;

-------set java classpath and give jar location--------
set classpath=%CLASSPATH%;../lib/MoveFiles.jar;

---------mention your fully classified name of java class to run, which was given in jar------
Java com.mits.MoveFiles
pause

Answer (score -2):

you shoult try this one :

```
java -cp youJarName.jar your.package.your.MainClass
```