# how to make java starter?

Tags: java

After having the jar, how to make a starter program (For example, in windows, an exe file) which can start the jar?

Comment: emmmm the jar should be executable assuming the makefile is correct

Comment: this requise JRE on path? right?

Comment: Possible duplicates (a) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows (b) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622062/batch-file-command-to-run-jar-file

Comment: What is the purpose of such a file if you can run jar file directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It works very well for building Java launchers for a project of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `.bat` file to run your `.jar`
Just create a new text file and write in it:

```
java -jar "filename.jar"
```

Save it and rename it to `whatever.bat`. Now in Windows you can run that `whatever.bat` file and your java program will be run.
Also, JRE has to be installed on the machine you will run this.

Comment: Also, colocate the .bat and the .jar, using `%~dp` to reference their shared parent directory.