# How do I create a desktop shortcut to start a .jar/.zip file?

Tags: java, cmd

I have a jar file `myJar.zip` . I open it from cmd

```
c:\users\owner>cd myfolder
c:\users\owner\myFolder>java -jar myJar.zip
```

How would I create a desktop shortcut that would do this ?

Comment: Read this link: [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) It talks about creating an executable from a `jar`. This link: [Executable JAR File](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html) will also help you. Cheers

Comment: Run this in the prompt `echo "java -jar c:\users\owner\myFolder\myJar.zip" > c:\users\owner\Desktop\foofoo.bat`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622062/run-jar-from-batch-file, second post.