# Java jar file not running

Tags: java

I have compiled my jar file using `jar cmf manifest.mf SysInfo.jar *.class` and got no errors, but when I try to execute the file by clicking on it nothing happens. I don't even get an error pop up. But when I run the jar using the console it will execute perfectly.

What can I do to make the file run by clicking it?

Comment: What kind of application is in the jar? Is it a command line app? Also, how are you running it from the command line (which command are you using)?

Comment: Please provide more information: How do you start it successfully from the console? How does the manifest file look like?

Comment: What os? Essentially you have to tell your os what to do with jar files.

Comment: **If Windows using console I/O and not GUI**: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446986/double-clicking-jar-file-does-not-open-command-prompt with alternate in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540902/cant-open-jar-using-double-click-only-with-cmd .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting it via console using

```
java -jar yourFile.jar
```

Don't forget to cd in the directory your .jar file is located before you do this.

EDIT: Sorry, you already said it works like that. Try right click open with.. and then choose open with javaw.exe
If that also doens't work you need to provide more information.

Comment: javaw only exists on Windows where it is already the default, and doesn't work if the program uses console I/O which I'm guessing is the problem, see links above.