# Java Windows. why can I run a jar file on command prompt but not double clicking it

Tags: java

Now on this machine earlier just typing in the command prompt:
java

resulted in the command prompt saying java wasn't recognized.
now the machine does have java installed , so I just added the java home and javahome/bin to path. and now pressing java causes java to be recognized but
by double clicking a jar file, but I am not getting the software to run. But when I go to command prompt and type in the prompt "java -jar nameofJar.jar" the application runs fine. Not sure what is the issue. I added the environment variables to make sure it targets the jar file. I do notice something its not seeing the jar file as a "Executable jar file" simple a "jar file".

Comment: You need to tell it to open it with `Java.exe`. That's what that command is doing.

Comment: Java.exe not javaw.exe ?

Comment: Afaik, it's java.exe. Again, afaik, `java -jar someJar.jar` just starts the `java` executable with the arguments `-jar someJar.jar`. I'd love to be corrected though.

Comment: It is definitely `javaw.exe`.  java.exe will open a command window every time, which I doubt is desired behavior.

Comment: @VGR So are they the same, except the `-w` version doesn't have a persistent prompt open? I've always just used `java`, but ya, it does have a background prompt open for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Correct.

Comment: If your program uses console I/O rather than (or in addition to) a GUI, you need `java.exe`; `javaw.exe` is for GUI-only programs. If you need the console display to remain after the program exits, so you can read the output for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446986/double-clicking-jar-file-does-not-open-command-prompt or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540902/cant-open-jar-using-double-click-only-with-cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell java to execute your file with `javaw.exe` as told by @Carcigenicate

1. Start "Control Panel"
2. Click "Default Programs"
3. Click "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program"
4. Double click .jar
5. Browse C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
6. Click the button Open
7. Click the button OK

Comment: I tried this method, and for some reason it still isn't causing the .jar file to be executed and the .jar file in the description is not saying its an executable.

Comment: Have a look at these [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows)

Comment: Would I need to do something with the registry on the windows machine as well?

Comment: well darn, still nothing. Do you thinking uninstalling and reinstalling the JRE again would help fix this issue ? I am still wondering why a computer with java installed would not be configured to know what java means in command prompt.

Comment: may something went wrong while installing java but you it should be the last option.

Comment: I do not know what may be wrong with the computer , when a jre is installed it should by default associate jar files with java executables. but for some reason it jar files were set with WinRAR -.-

Comment: well you gave me the best answer, I ended up updating the java version. but you did help a lot. so the points go to you Jack :)